# VideoView ViewPager black lines while swiping

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have a problem with `VideoView` and `ViewPager` swiping action. While swiping I can see black lines on the right or left side of `VideoView` (depends on side of swiping) . How can I deal with this.

It was done using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `ViewPager`. Parent `Activity` has `SurfaceView` with `0px` width and height and set
`getWindow( ).setFormat( PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT );`
I'm adding `VideoView` from `JAVA` code.

[image: screen one]
[image: screnn two]

Comment: VideoView is based of Surfaceview which is not very ideal for translation and other behaviours. and much more suited to full screen video players that are static in layout. What you are looking for is textureview based videoview. Try searching library on github.

Comment: @jayshah yeap, it helped. thx

Comment: @jayshah add this as answer. And I will mark it

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VideoView is based of Surfaceview which is not very ideal for translation and other behaviours. and much more suited to full screen video players that are static in layout. What you are looking for is textureview based videoview. Try searching library on github.

Comment: I used this library https://github.com/sprylab/texturevideoview/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/sprylab/android/widget/TextureVideoView.java#L1 worked pretty well

Answer (score 0):

you could try setting the background of the videoview to transparent.

```
videoView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```